# How to measure performance of outlier detection in time series with inexact labeled data

Tags: label, anomaly-detection

I have a principal question. Let's assume I have a time series (for example the time series below). Now I want to figure out which point is an anomaly. To label the data I am using an heuristic which says, everytime it is above 19, it is an anomaly. Now I am using a machine learning method and let it label the data and try to find out, how well the machine learning algorithm performed. I want to calculate recall, f1, precision etc. Since my heuristic is not exact and gives inexact labels, this is a bit challenging. For sure the heuristic found an outlier (where the value went to 20). But the real outlier might actually happen before. Actually the heuristic and the algorithm found the same outlier, only they mark the point in time a few seconds different. How do you deal with such inexact labels? Is there a way to tell the precision, recall, f1 etc. that the algorithm is actually better than this metrics think?

| TimeStamp | Value | Anomaly from heuristic | Anomaly from algorithm | TP/FP/TN/FN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | F | F | TN |
| 2 | 2 | F | F | TN |
| 3 | 5 | F | T | FP |
| 4 | 15 | F | F | TN |
| 5 | 20 | T | F | FN |
| 6 | 15 | F | F | TN |
| 7 | 5 | F | F | TN |
| 8 | 2 | F | F | TN |
| 9 | 1 | F | F | TN |
| 10 | 2 | F | F | TN |
| 11 | 1 | F | F | TN |
| 12 | 2 | F | F | TN |
| 13 | 1 | F | F | TN |

Comment: Until now I just found I few keywords which could help me. Things like "weakly labeled data", "weakly-superversized learning", "heuristic data labeling", library "snorkel", "automatically label data", "noisy training labels", "label noise","pseudo labels", "noisy class labels", "self-supervised learning", "inexact supervision", "noisy supervision", "inaccurate supervision", "average detection delay", "Instance-based Evaluation" - maybe that instance-based evaluation could help me, but I haven't really found what it is exactly. The label is correct, but it might show the wrong moment.

Comment: I also found a term "point-adjust approach". " If any point in an anomaly segment can be detected by the algorithm, we think this segment is detected correctly and all observations in the segment are considered to be correctly detected as anomalies."